# How would you say '[something] has been around'?

Tags: translation, phrase

I'm writing a report on nursing and I've been trying to figure out how to say nurses have been around since... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The most simple translation would probably be

> ...Krankenschwestern gibt es seit dem 17. Jahrhundert...

There is actually no need to revert to more complicated translations.